# what is the opposite of .has in javascript?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hello i am new to javascript and i have been trying to code a discord bot. Everything that i have done have been going well until i tried to make my bot give a role to someone. I wanted to make the bot send a message if someone did not have the role admin that he needed he would just type a single command and it would give it to him.

My code for the bot to give the role "Admin":

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'admin',
    description: "this is a role giving command!",
    execute(message, args){

        if(message.member.roles.cache.has('861973430189162538')){
            message.channel.send('You already have the role that you have requested!');


            
        }else if(message.member.roles.cache.has('861675046095028225')){  
            message.member.roles.add('861973430189162538').catch(console.error);
            message.channel.send('Here you go');

        }else if(message.member.roles.cache.not.has('861675046095028225')) {
            message.channel.send('You do not have the permissions to get this role!');

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't, you've to negate the entire value: `if (!message.member.roles.cache.has(...))`. In this particular case you don't need the second condition at all, though.

Comment: Presumably you don't need the if condition in your final else, since that would be true by construction?

Comment: Tried it SpoonMeiser didnt work

Comment: Teemu could you rephrase your comment because i didnt understand it properly

Comment: There is not an oppposite for `.has`. Instead, read the value and negate it with logical NOT operator (`!`). But as SpoonMeister also has stated, you don't need that second condition in this code, because that negated condition will always be `true` when the `else` part is executed.

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was the if and the .not.  
Now it works great